# Installing 12.04 onto a Dell studio with Windows 7 drops to grub rescue prompt

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, dual-boot, windows-7

Trying to install 12.04 on my brother's Dell Studio 1535 laptop with Windows 7 Ultimate already on it. After I tell the BIOS to boot USB, it tells me

```
error: no such device: 51d55cfe-ca94-40b7-8d22-180e1a1f9762
grub rescue>
```

and I can type in stuff. I used the same USB 5 minutes earlier to install 12.04 on my IBM Lenovo Z61m perfectly. So the USB is flashed right.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know if it is related, but I once had a person with a problem that his computer could not boot to a USB because it was formatted in FAT32

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem seems to be the corrupted grub. You may have to reinstall the grub because what my experience tell is that it is really messed up. You can use BOOT-REPAIR tool to do the repair task. But what I could use if I do not has any sort of thing?

I would rather use a pendrive having windows installer on it and would start the window repair to bring up the command prompt screen at boot time. Now, I would fix the MBR by-

```
x:\sources>bootsect.exe /fixmbr
```

If still there would be some problem, I would use the command-

```
x:\sources>bootsect.exe /fixboot
```

Maybe that could assist you as a workaround.

Comment: Are you trying to make `fixmbr` bold? It doesn't work in code blocks.